# cakephp named parameters break REST based web service

Tags: cakephp

I have a json REST based in the form of:

```
Router::mapResources('Test');
```

Which is equivalent to for the index method to:

```
Router::connect( '/Test',
                 array(
                      'controller' => 'ChannelSources', 
                      'action' => 'index', 
                      '[method]' => 'GET' ),
                 array();
```

I am trying to add support for named parameters this method.
but apparently its breaks the Router method as an index action is not part of the URL

i have tried using
    Router::connectNamed(array('somenameparam'));
But it failed.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a specific route so that you can pass in the right parameters, then you can pass your params into the route.

Have a look at, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action

```
Router::connect(
    '/blog/:id-:slug', // E.g. /blog/3-CakePHP_Rocks
    array('controller' => 'blog', 'action' => 'view'),
    array(
        // order matters since this will simply map ":id" to $articleId in your action
        'pass' => array('id', 'slug'),
        'id' => '[0-9]+'
    )
);
```